# Use Jira API with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, soap, jira

I have to write a Jira soap client with C# in Visual Studio 2010 but I have problems with getting die client class imported. The solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338944/net-wrapper-for-jira-api/580937#580937) doesn't seem to work anymore.

Though the class is accessible, all methods have the type

```
void Foo()
```

Also, the program "wsdl.exe", which was previously used to manually generate the client classes out of the WSDL files doesn't seem to exist any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web Service wizard is still available.  Right-click the project, Add Service Reference, Advanced, Add Web Reference.

Wsdl.exe is available in c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\bin

Comment: Alternative solution if you cannot use the 'Add Web Reference':
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22379843/766872