# Login to jira soap api

Tags: c#, api, soap, jira

I try use jira soap api on c#:

1. create new project in VS2010
2. add web service reference (JiraTest): `http://jira.atlassian.com/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl`
3. write next code:

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       var jiraLogin = "soaptester";
       var jiraPassword = "soaptester";
       var jiraClient = new JiraTest.JiraSoapServiceClient();
       var projects = jiraClient.getProjects();
   }
   ```

But this code throw exepition that I'm not autentificate yet.
I try find `login` method, but it have next signature:

```
public void login();
```

Where are no loginname and password parameters.
When I use this login method code throw exeption that login or password invalid. And I don't known where I must set my credentials.

How I can login with jira soap api before call needed method?

Added: see https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Creating+a+JIRA+SOAP+Client

Comment: When you search on the Atlassian page for "login", you will find the usage. Something like `jiraClient.login(jiraLogin, jiraPassword)` should work.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately there are only one login method and this method havn't parameters.

Comment: Could you add the information of the API (URL!!) to your question? I do not know, which API you use ...

Comment: If you look in the WSDL yourself you'll see the `<wsdl:message name="loginRequest">` has two string parameters. It looks like your client class was generated wrong.

Comment: @mliebert It's the JIRA SOAP API. The WSDL URL is in his step 2 and the API URL is at the bottom of that: `https://jira.atlassian.com/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2`

Comment: Really, my Visual Studio generate wrong wsdl. Thanks, Rup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
    JiraSoapServiceService jiraSoapService = new JiraSoapServiceService();

    public string Login(string user, string pwd)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        result = jiraSoapService.login(user, pwd);

        return result;

    }


    public void Logout(string token)
    {
        jiraSoapService.logout(token);
    }
```

Comment: This right, but I was confused, becouse my Visual Studio generate wrong class by wsdl (use next command: wsdl /language:CS http://jira.atlassian.com/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl)

Comment: I think u have to enabled RPC Plugin to create soap.  http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA042/Creating+a+SOAP+Client#

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and found the answer. You need to add it as a Web Reference. It will bring in the parameters but as they appear in the WSDL so login(string username, string password) become login(string in0, string in1) but atleast it's usable.

So steps:

- Right-click Project and click "Add Service References..." (just like before)
- Click "Advanced..." in the bottom left of the dialog
- Click "Add Web Reference..." in the bottom left of the dialog
- Enter the WSDL Url in the Url Box for example "https://jira.atlassian.com/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?WSDL"
- Click the green go arrow
- Name your reference in the Web reference name: box
- Click "Add Reference"

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in the same situation but could not go with the 'Web Service Service' solution as I needed to control the binding configuration (sendTimeout, maxReceivedMessageSize etc).

You can solve this by manually generating the JIRA WCF proxy via svcutil.exe. For instance:

```
 1. Run svcutil.exe http://myhostname/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2?wsdl /n:*,mynamespace
 2. Copy output source file to your project
 3. Copy configuration (output.config) to your app.config.
```